# Can't compile a GWT web application on Netbeans 6.9, throws error about build-gwt.xml

Tags: gwt, netbeans, toolkit

Just two days ago, I switched from Windows 7, and now run a Ubuntu 10.10 system, no multi-boot.

Anyway, after installing Netbeans, JDK, Tomcat and GWT4NB, I create an empty GWT project and hit "compile" to make sure everything works well...

This is what I get:

```
/home/loupax/NetBeansProjects/WebApplication2/nbproject/build-gwt.xml:138: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/loupax/NetBeansProjects/WebApplication2/nbproject/build-gwt.xml:166: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Line 138:  <antcall target="do-gwt-compile-15" />
Line 166: jvmargs="${gwt.compiler.jvmargs}">
```

Any ideas of what should I do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I have had the same problem. I tried to run the project on another computer, and its fail. My solution: right click on project in netbeans, select Change GWT SDK, point to gwt folder.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

click the
 Line 138:  
go to  deleter the three lines of antcall
and compile

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found out that my version of GWT4NB was not uptodate.
I installed a full featured plugin for NetBeans, which included GWT4NB, but I found out it didn't update its single components.
I'm going to re-install NetBeans, each plugin I need separately, then I'll link GWT Frameworok to new versions of GWT.